# How to Make PDF Form Sections Expand / Collapse

Tags: forms, acrobat, expand, livecycle

For print-out and offline electronic form purposes, I am looking for a way to create a form that has different sections that can be " Expanded / Collapsed " depending on which check-box is selected.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way, you can make prePrint Script like this:

```
sectionName.presence="visible"
```

or you can use checkBox Script like this:

```
if(this.rawValue==0){
    sectionName.presence="visible"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We use a 'default print' button which allows users to print the default blank form.

Here are the steps -

1. At the click of a button,  the user will be asked 'do you want to print the blank form?'
2. if yes, a function to hide/show subforms and fields will run
3. set a cursor focus to some dummy field so that the PDF layout is ready and we get the correct number of pages in step 5

   --> xfa.host.setFocus(some_dummy_field);
4. reset the data so that there is no filled in data in the blank form

   --> xfa.host.resetData();
5. count the total pages and call the native print function
   var totPages = xfa.layout.pageCount();
   totPages = totPages - 1;
   xfa.host.print(1, "0", totPages.toString(), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);